# Replicating Tx and Rx LEDs

Tags: arduino-uno

In my application all of the Arduino Uno LEDs will be invisible inside an enclosure, so I wish to provide panel-mounted Tx and Rx LEDS just replicating their on-board counterparts. Is there a way to drive any of the digital outputs to replicate those LEDs? I seem to recall that the Tx and Rx LEDs are driven directly from the FTDI logic, does this preclude hacking their states and sending them to two digital outputs? How could this be done? I could de-solder the LEDs and hardwire the panel LEDS to their pads, but I think this should be a last resort.

Answer (score 3):

The USB to serial and LEDs are done with the ATmega16U2 (the chip near the USB socket).

If you look closely you'll see there are 4 pad near the chip, JP2 in the [schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf). You could solder some wire to it to connect your leds. You could then slightly modify the [firmware running on the ATMega16u2](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/hardware/arduino/avr/firmwares/atmegaxxu2), and [upload it using DFU](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/DFUProgramming8U2).

I did this on my arduino uno to break out the reset signal, so I could use my UNO to program an separate ATMega328 over serial.

In your case you could use the pads connected to PB4 and PB5 (as the original code uses PD4 and PD5), so the you only have to change `DDRD` and `PORTD`, to `DDRB` and `PORTB` in [LED.h](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/firmwares/atmegaxxu2/arduino-usbserial/Board/LEDs.h).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do would likely be to use an Arduino that does not have an on-board serial connection such as the [Pro Mini](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardProMini) and then add a separate USB-UART bridge with either bare pads you can solder panel-mount LEDs to or mounting holes that will allow you to mount it with the LEDs aligned to holes on the enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would wrap all serial reading and writing in my own functions which, as well as doing the reading and writing, turn on an LED on any chosen GPIO and set a timer variable which is then used in the main loop to turn the LEDs off after a short period (otherwise they flicker too fast to be properly seen).  Something like:

```
uint32_t readLedTimer = 0;

// Call instead of Serial.read();
int mySerialRead() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        readLedTimer = millis();
        return Serial.read();
    }
    return -1;
}

// Call from loop();
void cancelLeds() {
    if ((readLedTimer > 0) && (millis() - readLedTimer > 20)) {
        readLedTimer = 0;
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    }
}
```

Of course, replicate (with a different LED) for the any Serial.write or Serial.print functions you may want to do (use may use *overloading* to pass different variable types to similar functions).

Another option is to directly modify the serial reading and writing routines within the Arduino AVR core to do the same thing, but that gets rather tricky when you update the IDE or want other people to use your code to build these widgets of yours.